# OnClick automático en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, onclick

Buenos días estoy tratando de crear un método en el cual se presione el botón refrescar automáticamente cada vez que entre al fragmento, me encuentro trabajando con un RecyclerView y cada vez que yo hago un cambio ya sea modificar, eliminar, agregar, etc. En el ReciclerView este se tiene que refrescar para eso cree un botón que refresca el fragmento y funciona todo muy bien sin embargo quiero que lo haga automáticamente al entrar al fragmento sin necesidad de presionar el botón, encontré una forma pero el botón se presiona cada cierto tiempo y yo lo que quiero es que se presione solo una vez cada que entre al fragmento este es el que encontré pero no me sirve de mucho pero quizá partiendo de este código pueda hacerlo de otra forma

```
refrescarUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_user, new UsuarioFragment()).commit();
}
}, 1000); // 1000 = 1 segundo - //Como ven con este código el método se ejecuta cada segundo pero 
                              yo quiero que se ejecute solo una vez
}}
```

spero que alguien me pueda ayudar de antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber cuando un `Fragmento` fue cargado completamente puedes usar el método `onActivityCreated()`, de acuerdo a el ciclo de vida del `Fragment`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo tanto sobre escribe este método y aquí puedes llamar el código para que automáticamente se "refresque" tu Fragment.

```
//Activity que contiene el Fragment ha terminado su creación.
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_user, new UsuarioFragment()).commit();
    }
    }, 1000);


}
```

Comment: Agradezco tu tiempo en responder pero lastimosamente sigo con el mismo problema el método Hanlder se actualiza cada segundo y pues como había dicho yo solo quiero que se actualice una vez cada que entra al fragment